# EventWaithandle vs while(true) Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a task class like below, a task could only start to run when its dependent task are completed.

```
class MyTask
{
    List<MyTask> dependentTasks;
    public TaskStatus Status;
    public EventWaitHandle CompletedEvent;
    public void Run() { }
}
```

I have two ways to achieve that, one is use EventWaitHandle like that:

```
EventWaitHandle.WaitAll(dependentTasks.Select<MyTask, EventWaitHandle>
    (t => t.CompletedEvent).ToArray());
```

Another way is use a while loop and check the status in dependent task list like that:

```
while (true)
{
    //Here I'm not sensitive on time, so delay 1 second is acceptable.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (dependentTasks.TrueForAll(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.Completed))
        break;
}
```

My question is which way is better in performance and why?

Comment: When you order a pizza do you get up and check the door once a minute until the pizza guy gets there, or do you just wait for him to ring your doorbell and go to the door once? Which of those two methods are better and why?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain:awesome man...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain brilliant, well said. Also, OP might want to look at [async and await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and [Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain awesome metaphor. gelivable

Comment: Also, note that the annoyance and waste of checking the door every minute is compounded by the fact that, on average, your pizza will be 30 seconds cooler.  I like my pizza hot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The truth is that performance likely isn't a significant factor here. The polling loop *will* use more CPU resources because once per second it has to check all of the tasks to see if they're completed. But that's a very small amount of processing. Still, the operating system has to schedule the thread to run once per second, which requires task switching, which will take away from the CPU resources available to your other tasks.

In your particular case, you say that a delay of 1 second isn't an issue. But for many people it would be. And in fact it could be for your application sometime in the future. Why add a delay if you don't have to?

`WaitAll` uses essentially no CPU resources while waiting.

A more important point is that the `WaitAll` code is more clear, easier to write, easier to prove correct, and harder to screw up. Seems like that would be the way to go.

Comment: Thread.Sleep *does* have a cost bigger than the once per second polling. It's not likely to be a big deal to most software as you won't have other threads, but if you start calling Thread.Sleep() in a threadpool or IO completion thread then you start running into problems where you starve other bits of your application of their turn.